# How to store a query result into a variable? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables and I want to store the result query of my stored procedure
into a variable.

`UserTable`:

```
UserID int primary key identity
CredentialsID int
AccountType nvarchar(15)
ModifiedDate date
```

`CredentialsTable`:

```
Credentials ID int primary key identity
Password
```

Stored procedure:

```
Create procedure addFaculty 
    @ID int 
as
begin
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select AccountType from UserTable where AccountType = 'Faculty')
    begin 
        Insert into CredentialsTable values ('iamafaculty');

        Select CredentialsTable.CredentialsID 
        from CredentialsTable 
        where CredentialsTable.Password = 'iamafaculty';
    end
end
```

Executing the select statement will return a credentialsID which I want to 
store in the `@ID` parameter. So I can use it on my other statements to be made.

Comment: To retrieve an identity value, after the insert stmt ,  you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() like SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() , and you don;t need of the last stmt (the select) . See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Is Scope_Identity() automatically returns the last value inserted in ANY table? Thanks man!

Comment: Oh okay i have read it already. Thanks again bro :) cheers!

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to set the ID variable parameter, you need to specify it as an OUTPUT parameter, and set it's value in your query:

```
Create procedure addFaculty 
@ID int OUTPUT
as
begin
    IF NOT EXISTS (Select AccountType from UserTable where AccountType = 'Faculty')
    begin 
        Insert into CredentialsTable values ('iamafaculty');

        Select @ID = CredentialsTable.CredentialsID 
        from CredentialsTable 
        where CredentialsTable.Password = 'iamafaculty';
    end
end
```

Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @sabin bio for this

Using the `Scope_Identity()` returns the last identity in any table in the current session. The scope of the `Scope_Identity()` is limited only to the current scope which is where the last insert statement has been made.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your stored proc declare parameters like below

```
 Create procedure addFaculty 
(
@ID int OUTPUT
)
as
begin
Insert into CredentialsTable values ('iamafaculty');

        Select @ID = CredentialsTable.CredentialsID 
        from CredentialsTable 
        where CredentialsTable.Password = 'iamafaculty';

end
```

Then finally while calling,retrieve the id value like below

```
declare @id1 int

exec addfaculty
@id=@id1 out
    select @id
```

Comment: I causes me an error. Sorry too late I saw your answer. You got the same answer with @Shane Estelle above. Thanks man. But I got a problem retrieving it